# CKEditor v4 : Dynamic title of dialog in homemade plugin

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm using CKEditor v4 and I made an homemade plugin (tu upload image and edit informations). 2 tabs (upload and edit informations) work good, but I want to set title of dialog using condition (new image or edit existing image). Is there a way to give a parameter to dialog fuciton when I call **CKEDITOR.dialog.add** or change the title on the onShow event or other issue ?

Thx a lot for your help and sorry for my frenchy english !

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and couldn't find an 'official' way, I was however able to change the title dynamically using following workaround (`this` is a CKEDITOR.dialog element):

`this.getElement().getFirst().find('.cke_dialog_title').getItem(0).setText('[insert new title here]')`

Basically, you go via the actual DOM of the dialog element (`getElement().getFirst()`), retrieve the title DOM element (`find('.cke_dialog_title').getItem(0)`), and set the text there. This relies solely on the CSS class name of CKEditor, so isn't really stable, but it's a start.

Answer (score 0):

$(dialog.parts.title.$).text(someTitleText)

in short:

```js
CKEDITOR.dialog.add('dynamictitle', function (editor) {
    ...
    ...
    return {
        title: "initial title here",
        ...
        ...
        //  set title onLoad(),or onShow()
        onLoad: function () {
            var currentTitle = editor.config.dynamictitle;
            var dialog = CKEDITOR.dialog.getCurrent();
            $(dialog.parts.title.$).text(currentTitle)
        }
    }
});

...
in your page:
CKEDITOR.replace('<ckeditorelementid>', {
        .....
        .....
        dynamictitle: <title text value>,
        .....
        .....
        });
```